# detecting touch on a particular area of screen

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I am trying to detect touch on a particular area of screen where if user taps I can do something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point=[touch locationInView:myView];
    NSLog(@"pointx: %f pointy:%f", point.x, point.y);
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(CGRectMake(5, 5, 40, 130),point));
    {
        NSLog(@"touched here");                     
    }   
}
```

But this message is displayed even when I touch anywhere on the screen. I want it to be displayed only when I touch `myView`.

I tried setting `point.x` and `point.y` to different numbers but that doesn't work?
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code quoted will always return YES because you are asking for the point within the view in question because points can have a negative location in a view. To get only touches in your view, use:

```
if ([touch view] == myView)
```

Comment: If an answer works, please accept it. This will encourage others to answer your questions too.

Comment: not working?? malso myview can b an imageview or a webView?? tried both with above but not working

Comment: if myView is a UIImageView, you have to add the following line:

myView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;